# Python webbrowser: how to open a svg file with Firefox under Windows?

Tags: python, file, browser, python-webbrowser

I try to open a svg file with firefox browser under Windows 7 (firefox version: 19.0.2) using Python's `webbrowser` module:

```
import webbrowser

chart_path = "C:\\my_file\\mysvg.svg"
browser = webbrowser.get('mozilla')
browser.open(chart_path)
```

But I get this error:

```
    browser = webbrowser.get('mozilla')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\webbrowser.py", line 52, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

What is wrong here? I also tried it with `"firefox"` name. But I got a similar error.

When I do:

```
print webbrowser._browsers
```

I get:

```
{'windows-default': [<class 'webbrowser.WindowsDefault'>, None], 'c:\\program files\\internet explorer\\iexplore.exe': [None, <webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser object at 0x02F81B90>]}
```

Comment: I'd guess it can't find Firefox if it isn't in your PATH.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: You may be right. Please see my post again. Is there a workaround? I can't edit PATH, because it is restricted in my PC.

Comment: Having Firefox installed is also restricted to your PC. ;-) Have you tried using Windows-default as browser?

Comment: Internet Explorer 8 can't open svg files.

Comment: Ah. Then you probably need to figure out where Firefox is installed by looking in the registry. But that might be dependent on the version of Firefox...

Comment: OK, after finding its location, what am I going to do?

Comment: I think you can pass in a path to webbrowser.get(), and if not you can start it with a system call.